# gRaphael Library: Can't Create Line Chart

Tags: javascript, raphael, linechart, graphael

I'm using the gRaphael JavaScript library, and am attempting to draw a simple line graph.
The code I currently have on the page is:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 640, 480);
paper.g.linechart(10,10,300,220,[1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,15,35,30]);
</script>
```

I found this code from a tutorial, located here: https://github.com/kennyshen/g.raphael/blob/master/examples/linechart/linechart_basic.html

All the required files, **raphael.js**, **g.raphael.js**, and **g.line.js**, are included earlier on the page as well.

When I view the page, it just shows up as a white screen.  Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

After looking through the source code, it looks like they changed the syntax for g.raphael (but then didn't update their homepage) so that now it's just

```
paper.linechart
```

instead of

```
paper.g.linechart
```

In the demo page for the linechart, http://g.raphaeljs.com/linechart.html, you can see the syntax if you look at the page source